# Visual Studio Project "Release" (x86) build can not load a DLL (msobj100.dll)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a really simple project that I am trying to build with Visual Studio 2010 Express (x64) edition (C++). It contains only 1 file (main.cpp) that is used to find the machine epsilon on my machine and does nothing else. When I try to compile a Debug x86 build everything works fine and an .exe is generated but I would like to make a release build as I need to turn this code is as a HW assignment. When I try and compile a Release (x86) build it fails with the following error -

1>LINK : fatal error LNK1296: unable to load msobj100.dll

I ran a search and the only place I found a file called msobj100.dll is in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64" so I tried adding that location to the solution's VC Directories -> Executable Directories line. It didn't work. Why does the Release build complain about this DLL when the Debug build does not? I have compared both build pages and can not seem to find any differences in their dependencies or directory locations. I would really like to know what is going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to load the 64-bit DLL in your x86 application, you can probably find msobj100.dll in `C:\Windows\SysWow64`

Comment: Can you be more specific on how to remedy this problem?  I'm having this issue on Windows 7, and the only place msobj100.dll exists is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE.  In C:\Windows\SysWow64, there is, however, a file called msobjs100.dll (note the 's').

Comment: Sorry, the file in SysWow64 and Win32 is jus msobjs.dll.