# VS 2010 C++ cannot load msobj100.dll in Release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, visual-studio-express

I have a fairly simple C++ project in Visual C++ 2010 Express on Windows 7.  I have no problems compiling in Debug mode for Win32, but when I switch to Release mode for Win32 I get the following compiler error:

LINK : fatal error LNK1296: unable to load msobj100.dll

I know this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296476/visual-studio-project-release-x86-build-can-not-load-a-dll-msobj100-dll), but I couldn't get a fix from that solution.  I did a search for that file, and it is only located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE.  Within SysWOW64 and Win32, there are files called 'msobjs.dll', but that's it.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you are trying to build a 64-bit program then you should mention that.

Comment: @HansPassant: Updated the question, and it's for Win32

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the Windows SDK to your computer. These Files Should be distributed.Along with it. 
See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this didn't work.  I say that because I don't have admin privileges, so IT said they installed it (and had to reinstall Visual Studio in fact), but that did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the missing dll file from

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE`
to
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin`.

`VC\Bin` is the runtime path.

This problem also bothered me for a long time, and I had to run Release mode in another machine...
and I find the solution just now.